# A problem with natural log when dealing with complex numbers

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, logarithms, complex-integration

The definition of the natural log of a complex number:
$$\ln(z) = |z| \ + \ i\arg(z)$$

The definition of the natural log:
$$\ln(t) = \int_{1}^{t} \frac{1}{x} \ dx$$ for any real $t > 0$.

I actually wanted to derive Euler's formula:
$$e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$$

The procedure is as follows:

$$z(x) = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x} = -\sin(x) + i\cos(x) = i(i\sin(x) + \cos(x)) = iz$$
$$\therefore \int \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z} = \int i \ dx$$
$$ \therefore \ln|z| = ix$$
$$\therefore |z| = e^{ix}$$
$$\therefore z = \pm \ e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$$

With my limited knowledge that the integral of $1/z$ is always $\ln|z| + C$, I reached a wrong conclusion. However, I could resolve the problem by defining $\ln(z)$ as an indefinite integral of any complex number. But as I mentioned at the top, the definition of the natural log does not involve any complex number. The definition of the natural log with a complex number does not give me such an intuitive way of understanding it.

I am confused with a bunch of things that I can't even say where I'm confused. Can anybody clarify?

Comment: I think maybe your mistake was mixing up complex derivatives with real partial derivatives. Very different things.

Comment: You cannot handle complex logarithms this way.

Comment: Yes. I am a high school student and I don't know much about complex analysis. That's why I need clarification of a quite broad range of things.

Answer (score 2):

Cutting to the chase, I will say: It is not true that 
$$ \int \frac{1}{z} dz = \ln ( |z|) +C $$ 
This is true for real numbers, but even there you need to be careful about what you mean, since - for instance - this function is not defined at 0.

Your present path to proving Euler's formula is on the right track, but probably not the easiest path. This is basically due to the fact that $\ln(z)$ is multivalued in the complex case. (This is related to both the complex exponential and the fact that the integral $$ \int_{1}^1 \frac{1}{z} dz$$ is not necessarily $0$, as well as the fact that $e^{2 \pi i} =1 $. These facts are themselves related, and are at the heart of complex analysis.)

An easier way would be: $f(x) = \cos(x) + i \sin(x) $, and $g(x) = e^{ix}$. Then, in case case: $f'(x) = if(x)$ and $g'(x) = ig(x)$. Then, compute: 
$\left( \frac{f}{g} \right)'(x) = = \frac{ g(x) f'(x) - f(x) g'(x)}{g(x)^2} = \frac{ i (f(x)g(x) - g(x)f(x))}{g(x)^2} = 0$. Last, compute $f(0)$, $g(0)$.

Comment: Why is integral from 1 to 1 not 0?

Comment: This is one of the interesting things that happens in complex analysis. Since we're in two dimensions, when we say $ \int_1^1$ we have to define a path through the plane along which we do the integral as normal. We could just choose the null-path from $1 \to 1$ ie. just stay at one. We could also choose the unit circle. Parameterize the unit circle by $z(t) = e^{2 \pi i t }$. Then, $dz = 2 \pi i z(t)$, and for the integral we have $\int_1^1 \frac{1}{z} = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{z(t)} 2 \pi i z(t) = \int_0^1 2 \pi i = 2 \pi i$. So, in this case: the value of the integral depends on the path.

Comment: It could be $0$ depending on which path you choose, but it could also be non zero. Interestingly, the value of the integral depends only on the net number of times the path circles the origin. The value will be $2 \pi i ( \text{ number of times traversed counterclockwise} - \text{number of times traversed clockwise})$

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: Yep, thank you!